# Перехват AJAX запросов в расширении

Tags: ajax, chrome-extension

Заказчик хочет что бы расширение перехватывало запросы AJAX и перед отправкой по нужному адресу отправляло на его сервер. Это нужно для сотрудников, а не для всех. Так что не надо писать это не хорошо и т.д.

Пишу вот такое в content.js:

```
    (function(send) {
        XMLHttpRequest.prototype.send = function() {
            console.log('ajax');
            send.apply(this, arguments);
        };
    })(XMLHttpRequest.prototype.send);
```

Но вот это не работает. Пытался в `window.onload` и вне его. выставлял разные типы `run_at` в `manifest.json`.

А вот если я этот же код исполню из консоли то все работает. Что я не так делаю?

`manifest.json`

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "Sender",
  "version": "1",
  "permissions": [
    "tabs",
    "activeTab",
    "http://*/*",
    "https://*/*",
    "storage",
    "downloads"
  ],
  "icons": {
    "48": "48x48.png"
  },
  "background": {
    "scripts": [
      "jquery.js",
      "bg.js"
    ]
  },
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": [
        "https://*/*",
        "http://*/*"
      ],
      "js": [
        "cryptojs.js",
        "jquery-3.3.1.min.js",
        "content.js"
      ],
      "run_at": "document_idle"
    }
  ],
  "browser_action": {
    "default_title": "Open",
    "default_icon": "48x48.png",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  }
}
```

Comment: А в каком контексте вы это делаете ? Вы же понимаете, что JS код расширения находиться в песочнице и любые изменения вносимые в поведение JS объектов действуют только внутри кода данного расширения и никак не влияют на код сайта. т.е. вы не можете таким образом модифицировать поведение объекта сайта. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/796255/194569

Comment: Рекомендую посмотреть расширения вроде fregate, они получают доступ ко всей информации передаваемой из браузера, цепляясь за совершенно другие функции и даже умудряются подсовывать в нужный момент прокси. А если вы трафик клиента весь прогоните через прокси, то сможете весь его записать

Comment: @Mike но ведь content.js имеет доступ к DOM, а значит и к объектам тоже. разве нет?

Comment: К DOM да, к объектам JS-кода - нет. Весь JS код у него свой, полностью изолированный от сайта.

Comment: @Mike не могу найти расширение fregate в магазине.

Comment: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/frigate3-proxy-helper/hdbipekpdpggjaipompnomhccfemaljm  или https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/frigate-cdn-smooth-access/mbacbcfdfaapbcnlnbmciiaakomhkbkb?hl=ru

Answer (score 1):

Для этого существует [chrome.webRequest API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest). 
В вашем случае необходимо установить обработчик на событие **onBeforeRequest**.

Что-то типо:

```
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(function (requestObj) {

    // requestObj - объект запроса

}, {urls: ['*://*/*']}, ['requestBody']);
```

Если требование сначала перенаправить данные на сторонний сервер, а затем продолжить запрос является необходимым, то это вы сможете выполнить только с применением [синхронного XHR](https://learn.javascript.ru/ajax-xmlhttprequest#%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%85%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%B8-%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%85%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%8B).

Не забудьте добавить "webRequest" в manifest.json > permissions.